# Laravel Facade get Variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, facade

Say we have the following class in Laravel

```
class myClass {
    private $_someArray;

    // Functions to manipulate $_someArray
    public function someArray() {
        return $this->_someArray;
    }
}
```

I have declared a Facade and an Alias. So I can get access to `$_someArray` by calling `myClass::someArray()` and it's attributes by `myClass::someArray()['key']`.

Is there a way I could get the array without calling a function? i.e. I would like to be able to do something like `myClass::someArray['key']`

Comment: You can't do that. `PHP` has `__get` for property overloading but it works only on instance/object.

Comment: @TheAlpha and it doesn't work on Facades :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to user a function that retrieves an object with properties.

```
MyFacade::getSomeObject()->myProperty;
```

as an example, function can take data from class constants or from class variables and combine them if needed:

```
public function getSomeObject()
{
    $result = new \stdClass();
    $result->id = self::SOME_ID;        
    $result->myProperty = $this->someProperty;
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, facade is calling providers methods,not properties through Facades **__callStatic** method.

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $instance = static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());

        switch (count($args))
        {
            case 0:
                return $instance->$method();

            case 1:
                return $instance->$method($args[0]);

            case 2:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);

            case 3:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);

            case 4:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);

            default:
                return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't really answer the question :(

Answer (score -1):

this way works:

```
myClass::$_someArray
```